# Difference between prepositions for and of

Tags: for

1. Is this the last exam of you guys?
2. Is this the last exam for you guys?

Could you explain which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1):

They're both grammatical. The first is also called a [physical examination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_examination) with the guys as patients - in this case, the final in a series of check-ups. The second could refer to the same, but is more commonly understood as the final [test](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exam) taken by the guys in a course of study.

Answer (score 1):

Using **of** carries implications that something of the guys is being examined, like eyes.

Using **for** carries the implication that what is being tested is separate from them themselves.

So if you are talking to a group of Army recruits being processed into basic training, then **of** may be correct, but a group of college students during exam week, **for** is correct.